# Django - context modified when passing to template

Tags: python, django

I have a function which return a presign url for a S3 object, and I want to use it in my template.

Here is my function in views.py:

```py
def player_index(request):
    mpd_url = update_file.mpd_url()
    vtt_url = update_file.vtt_url()
    context = {
        'mpd_url': mpd_url,
        'vtt_url': vtt_url,
    }

    return render(request,'index.html',context)
```

and here is a part of my template with context:

```
var url = '{{ mpd_url }}';

player.vttThumbnails({
  src: '{{ vtt_url }}'
});
```

But it seems like urls doesn't match in my function and in my template:
when I print it in views.py : `https://realtime-video-logs.s3.amazonaws.com/test/manifest.mpd?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAVT3T733IUIUYBBMB&Signature=ZA9mgVjXvBShKAdvjw6hgeOwC1o%3D&Expires=1563980730`

and in my template : `https://realtime-video-logs.s3.amazonaws.com/test/thumbs.vtt?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAVT3T733IUIUYBBMB&amp;Signature=jqDfi15GLB77DmzrNkVn743HPdA%3D&amp;Expires=1563981729`

the '&' is replace by ';' and I don't understand why.

Comment: The `&` is replaced with `&amp;`, since otherwise the browser would not render `&`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is logical, Django HTML encodes the strings. For example, if your text contains an `&` then Django will replace it with `&amp;`, otherwise the `&` would not be visible.

You can turn this off by applying the [**`|safe`** template filter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#safe) to it. Django will then:

> **Marks a string as not requiring further HTML escaping** prior to output. When autoescaping is off, this filter has no effect.

For example:

```
var url = '{{ mpd_url|safe }}';

player.vttThumbnails({
  src: '{{ vtt_url|safe }}'
});
```